# NodeJS - How to wait for multiple Async calls to finish before continuing execution flow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function `getAliasesByRoleDetailed(role)` that takes care of fetching user data given a `role` (this function uses axios to fetch data).

The output of this function is something like this:

```
[     
    {
        alias: 'xxxx',
        Role: 'Admin',
        grantedBy: 'rnfnf',
        timestamp: '1591375676333'
    },
    {
        alias: 'vbjp',
        Role: 'Admin',
        'Granted By': 'hjkds',
        timestamp: '1588013678236'
    }
]
```

It is possible to do something like this:

```
const response = await getAliasesByRoleDetailed(role);
```

and then keep doing stuff with `response` once the data is available.

But what if I want to make multiple calls to this `getAliasesByRoleDetailed(role)` function and `.push()` the results into an array before moving on with the code execution?

1. I want to execute the `getAliasesByRoleDetailed(role)` for each element in an array like `['Admin','Trainer','Manager']` and push the results of each execution into a `resultsArray`.
2. **After** all calls have finished and the results are available in the `resultsArray`, I'd like to continue with my logic, using the `resultsArray` data.

So, ideally:

```
//Inside a function...

[getting data using getAliasesByRoleDetailed(role) ...]

resultsArray.forEach( (e) => {
    //Do something useful with all these element I now have!
}
```

I've tried a couple of solutions with async/await and `.forEach()` but keep getting stuck. Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd probably want to make use of [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

This will wait for all the inner promises (promises passed into the function) to resolve before resolving itself.

```js
// inside an async function

const roles = ['Admin', 'Trainer', 'Manager'];

const results = await Promise.all(roles.map(role => {
  return getAliasesByRoleDetailed(role);
}));

// results should now have all the results available
```

You can then flatten the array using [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
// inside the same function
const flattenResults = Array.flat(results);
```

Comment: This is awesome, it worked great and the `Array.flat` helps a lot. I appreciate your help (and everyone else's, too)!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Check out also Sven.hig's answer as he pointed out you might want to use `Promise.allSettled` in case one of the requests fails. Depends on your error-handling strategy :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned async/await, I assume that `getAliasesByRoleDetailed` returns a `Promise`. Therefore, you have to do something like

```
let resultsArray = await Promise.all(['Admin','Trainer','Manager'].map(getAliasesByRoleDetailed))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = await data.reduce(async (promise, value) => {
        await promise;

        let response = await getAliasesByRoleDetailed(value.Role);
        //do something with response
        return response;
      }, Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider to use Promise.all: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

In your situation, you can try this:

```
Promise.all(['Admin','Trainer','Manager'].map(getAliasesByRoleDetailed)).then(resultsArray => {
  // do your stuff
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)
Promise.all will resolve only when all of the promises have resolved
hence why I think you should probably use Promise.allSettled() as it waits for all promises to complete regardless if one of them is rejected

```js
roles=['Admin','Trainer','Manager']
var result=Promise.allSettled(roles.map(r=>getAliasesByRoleDetailed(role)))
```

Comment: That's very insightful, thank you for your help. I appreciate this clarification and I will have to think which one best fits my needs. I might want it to fail if someone passes invalid data -maybe not, will think about it ... :)